# Did the U.S. Army treat a President's cold using chlorine gas?

Tags: medical-science, united-states, history, chlorine

Several texts on the history of chemical warfare mention the story that in May 1924 the U.S. Army Chemical Warfare Service (CWS) treated President Calvin Coolidge for a severe cold with chlorine. For example:

> In May 1924 the CWS sealed President Calvin Coolidge into a gas chamber  and pumped in low levels of chlorine gas to cure his cold. After 45 minutes inside the chamber, Coolidge 
>   emerged and returned to work.

(T. I. Faith, *Under a Green Sea: The US Chemical Warfare Service 1917–1929,* Dissertation submitted to The George Washington University, May 18, 2008)

In all relevant texts that I have found, the original source of this story is the newspaper article [“Army’s Chlorine Gas Helps Coolidge’s Cold; He Spends 45 Minutes in Air-Tight Room”, *The New York Times,* May 21, 1924, Page 1](http://query.nytimes.com/gst/abstract.html?res=9D01E6D71F3CE733A25752C2A9639C946595D6CF).

The CWS organized and financed various publicity campaigns in order to prove their importance; however, such a potentially dangerous publicity stunt seems to be excessive since it was known that exposure to chlorine could cause damage to one’s health, including delayed pulmonary oedema. This makes me doubt whether the story is absolutely true. Could the newspaper article be exaggerated in any way? Are there any other references for this story?

Comment: Wait, did chlorine really cure his cold? Aside from the side effects of breathing it, I'm skeptical that it could do that...

Comment: @Michael "VALUE OF CHLORIN IN THE TREATMENT OF COLDS " JAMA. 1925;84(22):1629-1632 http://jama.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=235758 is considered to have disproven the effectiveness of chlorine treatments

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes, President Coolidge was treated in a sealed room with chlorine gas on 3 consecutive days (May 20-22, 1924).

On the second day he [brought his wife into the room](http://query.nytimes.com/gst/abstract.html?res=9C0CE3D71F3CE733A25751C2A9639C946595D6CF) even though she wasn't sick.  He liked the treatment so much he is quoted by [American Review vol. 71](https://books.google.com/books?id=jMoCAAAAMAAJ&q=%22you%20must%20go%20down%20and%20take%20a%20chlorine%20treatment%22&dq=%22you%20must%20go%20down%20and%20take%20a%20chlorine%20treatment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn2Z29rObMAhWKGD4KHQwRAVoQ6AEIIDAB) as saying to [Bishop Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_F._Anderson_(bishop)):

> You must go down and take a chlorine treatment.  I recently cured a bad cold in that manner and I know you will be relieved

[image]

Caption:

> Col. M.A. DeLaney, U.S.A., the man who has been treating Pres. Coolidge on May 22nd while the Pres. was in the air-tight room receiving the chlorine gas treatment for his cold. Col. DeLaney is watching the apparatus that denotes the amount of gas being sent into the air-tight chamber

Source: [US Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/item/hec2013002919/)

In addition to the President, according to [War and Nature](https://books.google.com/books?id=pDW4YNkmvZYC&pg=PA63&dq=23%20senators%20chlorine%20gas&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjenNiquOfMAhVJ2IMKHfrDA24Q6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=23%20senators%20chlorine%20gas&f=false) :

> In a room near the Senate Appropriations Committee, the Chemical Warfare Service gassed more than 750 people, including 23 senators and 146 representatives.

See also:

[Poison Gases of War to Cure Human Ills](https://books.google.com/books?id=wdoDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA353&dq=coolidge%20chlorine&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTtdK3pubMAhVEcz4KHT1gBE8Q6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=coolidge%20chlorine&f=false), *Popular Mechanics*, September 1924, vol. 42, pages 353-354.

[Coolidge Tries Chlorine Gas to Dispel Cold](http://archives.chicagotribune.com/1924/05/21/page/1/article/coolidge-tries-chlorine-gas-to-dispel-cold) *Chicago Tribune* 21 May 1924, front page.

[Coolidge Converted to Chlorine Gas Treatment](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=266&dat=19240523&id=wtorAAAAIBAJ&sjid=TEYEAAAAIBAJ&pg=2230,6110365&hl=en) *Kentucky New Era* 23 May 1924, front page.

Advertisement [Stops Your Cold or Costs Nothing: Vapo Chlorine, the Genuine Home Chlorine Gas Chamber Set](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1144&dat=19250219&id=9TQbAAAAIBAJ&sjid=CEoEAAAAIBAJ&pg=6365,6444796&hl=en) in *Pittsburg Post Gazette* , 17 February 1925.

[Chlorine for Colds](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1949-8594.1925.tb04954.x/abstract) March 1925.

[The Present Status of Chlorine Gas Therapy](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2262343/) Trans Am Climatol Clin Assoc. 1925; 41: 203–216

Research refuting the effectiveness of such treatments was published in [VALUE OF CHLORIN IN THE TREATMENT OF COLDS](http://jama.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=235758) JAMA. 1925;84(22):1629-1632

Comment: the combination of the source and the caption are the answer here. The picture doesn't show anything. On it's own it really won't prove anything. It might be an idea to make the source and and caption more prominent

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit? Honestly I have no idea whats going on here. From the title of the question it sounds like the army is torturing the president and thats clearly not whats going on here.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Over a three day period May 20-22, 1924, the president inhaled chlorine gas to help his cold.  It was thought to be healthy at that time.

Comment: @DavePhD It probably helped the symptoms.  Several years ago, I worked with a girl whose grandmother was dying of lung cancer.  She got started smoking, back in the day, on the advice of her doctor, because the hot air would be good for her asthma!

Comment: Does history relate the concentration used?

Comment: @AE yes, "When breathing a concentration of 0.015 mgm. of chlorine per
liter of air for one hour, which is the concentration and time used in
treatment of cases, approximately 550 liters of air are inhaled and
exhaled, containing approximately 2.5 cc. of pure gaseous chlorine.
We have found by actual experiment that none of this chlorine is
exhaled. Therefore, in the course of an hour from 2.5 to 3 cc. of
chlorine is absorbed into the fluid of the respiratory tract." http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2262343/

Comment: So... does it work?

Comment: @T.Verron The last paper linked in the answer seems to suggest that it does.

Comment: @T.Verron This 1945 British Medical Journal article says "yes" http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2057467/ more like a letter to the editor than a good study though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm skeptical...

Comment: @DavePhD That letter really gives me shivers. He talks about the people he tried it on as "victims" and being "persuaded" to try his treatment.

Comment: @Erik I think he means victims of the cold, not the experiment: "The victim is persuaded to attend the
first-aid room once an hour, when the unstoppered bottle is
held under his nose, and he must sniff sufficiently hard to make
him cough."

Comment: @DavePhD - I think that might be the key thing here.  The victim coughs, potentially dislodging mucus from the lungs, which can help to relieve cold symptoms.  I feel like there are safer ways of making someone cough nowadays.  But you're the one with a PhD (medical?), so I'll defer to your expertise.  I just know when I have a cold that coughing up mucus generally helps.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman chemistry, not really medical

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, well, chlorine _is_ poisonous to the bacteria. With the right dosage it might be enough to kill the bacteria (which are concentrated in the respiratory tract, which is most exposed), but not the patient, so it might actually work, although likely with bad side-effects.

Comment: But a cold is viral, not bacterial

Comment: Exposure to chlorine gas can still render viruses ineffective.  That's why drinking water systems treat water supplies with chlorine - it's a general disinfectant even at low concentrations:  http://www.cdc.gov/safewater/effectiveness-on-pathogens.html